# Error in function call in R

Tags: r

I've written a function to take two vectors, say x and y and I'm returning another vector with values:
sum(x), sum(y) and sum(x)/sum(y).

the code i have written is:

```
> anotherFunction<-function(x,y){
+ return (c(sum(x),sum(y),(sum(x)/sum(y))))
+ }
```

I've used this function as follows:

> summaryBy(Age~age.groups,data=testdata,FUN=anotherFunction(testdata$Clicks,testdata$Impressions))

I've got the following error:

Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "currFUN"

Can someone please point out my mistake and tell me how can I correct it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally speaking, `FUN` should just be the name of the function. But regardless, I don't think that a function with two arguments is going to work the way you think it will.

Comment: @noah: yes. summaryBy from the doBy package

Comment: @joran : I'm a newbie to R, so there is a good chance that the code I have written is not the recommended form. I guess I'll have to change the way I think and understand code when programming in R

Comment: I don't use **doBy** much, but I believe that `summaryBy` is intended to produce summaries for each variable on the left side of your formula, grouped by variables on right side of your formula. You might find `ddply` from **plyr** a little more intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible using `summaryBy` for reasons mentioned in the comments, but using `plyr` as suggested it is quite simple:

```
library(plyr)

anotherFunction<-function(x, y){
    return (c(sum.x = sum(x),
              sum.y = sum(y),
              ratio = (sum(x)/sum(y))))
}
## test data
testdata <- data.frame( Age = sample(18:30, 15, replace=TRUE),
                  Clicks = sample(10:100, 15, replace = TRUE),
                  Impressions = sample(10:100, 15, replace = TRUE))
testdata$age.groups <- as.numeric(cut(dat$Age, breaks = 3))

mySummary <- ddply(testdata, .(age.groups), .fun = function(x) {
    anotherFunction(x$Clicks, x$Impressions) })
```

And you'll get something like this:

```
> mySummary
  age.groups sum.x sum.y     ratio
1          1   326   350 0.9314286
2          2   130   202 0.6435644
3          3   293   416 0.7043269
```